# Consumer is not authorized to access %resources Magento_Sales::sales

Tags: magento2, api, sales-order, rest-api

I have this basic API script:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(-1);

    $usr = [
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'somePassword'
    ];

    $ch = curl_init('https://magentostore/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($usr));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json', 'Content-Length: '. strlen(json_encode($usr))]);

    $token = curl_exec($ch);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($token);
    echo '</pre>';

    echo '========================';

    $ch = curl_init('https://magentostore/index.php/rest/V1/orders/1');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: Bearer '. json_decode($token)]);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    $result = json_decode($result, 1);
    echo '<pre>'. print_r($result) .'</pre>';
```

but it returns this message:

> Array ( [message] => Consumer is not authorized to access %resources [parameters] => Array ( [resources] => Magento_Sales::sales ) )

I'm not sure why, my script should work but I can't figure out why? Is it because of `username` account permissions? Shouldn't be as user = admin. Just trying to get array of orders ...

Alternative testing method that yielded same results:

I did:

```
curl -X POST 'https://magentostore/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token' \
-H 'Content-Type:application/xml' \
-d '<login><username>admin</username><password>password</password></login>'
```

which got me the Token, which I then used like this:

```
curl -X GET https://magentostore/index.php/rest/V1/orders/1' -H 'Authorization: Bearer <Token that was returned>'
```

which gets me the same error as above

Edit:

I've tried with a few different API Endpoints and some work (like getting categories) but `/orders` still doesn't. I've tried on 3 separate environments and only 1 works:

**Env One - Doesn't Work**

- OS: CentOS 7
- PHP Version: 7.1
- Magento Version: 2.2.5
- Hosted outside of LAN

**Env Two - Doesn't Work**

- OS: CentOS 7
- PHP Version: 7.0
- Magento Version: 2.2.5
- Hosted outside of LAN

**Env Three - DOES WORK**

- OS: Linux Mint 19
- PHP Version: 7.2
- Magento Version: 2.3-develop
- localhost

Comment: are you sure you passing admin's username and password correct.

Comment: @AdityaShah as sure as a sea

Comment: Okay, do you have POSTMAN ?

Comment: @AdityaShah no .. seems not needed? Just a way to develop APIs in IDE-format no?

Comment: No, just to get token with url - just for testing purpose

Comment: @AdityaShah I var dump my token above ^^ seems to work - it just doesn't have correct access rights (think it's user-level - not tokens)

Comment: Yeah - i am posting a code for get token, okay ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83907/discussion-between-aditya-shah-and-thisguyhastwothumbs).

Comment: Hey there, please post your case and solution here it will be helpful for future readers (:

Comment: @AdityaShah no. Solution found yet :( need to do more debugging of the non vanilla Magento to find root cause

Comment: Wait.. put PHP debugger in the code.. it will show the root files and it's calling functions

Comment: @AdityaShah I has PHPStorm so I can just click through, need to git diff the files me reckons to see if core hacks have been made

Answer (score 8):

**1. First setup Integrations**

> Open the System > Extensions > Integrations

[image]

> Add New Integration

[image]

> Set the integration **Name** and other settings, then specify your
>   Magento 2 back-end password in the **Your Password** field

[image]

> Switch to the **API** sidebar tab and select the resources which will
>   be available to **OAuth clients**:

[image]

> Press the **Save** button. The **integration** will be saved and the
>   **Integrations** list will be shown again. Press the **Activate** link in the integration row:

[image]

> A confirmation screen will be shown. Press the **Allow** button

[image]

> The credentials screen will be shown.
>     Use them in your third-party software to access your Magento 2 as OAuth server.
>
> **You will see:**
>
> - Consumer Key
> - Consumer Secret
> - Access Token
> - Access Token Secret
>
> Copy it to somewhere, then press the **Done** button.

[image]

> The integration will be saved and the **Integrations** list will be
>   shown again. You will see your integration in the **Active** state:
>   [image]

**2. Now get admin token**

---

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://magento.host/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token?username=admin&password=admin123",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Postman-Token: b7d053fe-df0d-4a85-ab82-4093a9be9d15"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

**3. add that Admin token**

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://magento.host/index.php/rest/V1/orders/1",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR ADMIN TOKEN>",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Postman-Token: 1057fee5-abde-4a88-bd39-2a623ca995e6"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Comment: same error :/ - just a different way of getting to it

Comment: woh, share me your actual url

Comment: forget about it, just tell me are you getting any admin TOKEN ?

Comment: yeah I do - it's already specified in question ^^

Comment: But there's no other possibilities.

Comment: Okay pass that Authentication token direct in the script.

Comment: Tried that - same issue :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83910/discussion-between-aditya-shah-and-thisguyhastwothumbs).

Comment: can i combined the code in one page ?

Comment: I use admin token and it working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same Problem. In my case, the response of the token was wrapped in "", which passed to the next calling function could of cause not work. So I just stripped the "" from the response, and than it worked for me. Here is my working code to update the stock of an item via sku:

```
$config = array(
    'shop_url' => "%YOUR_SHOP_URL%",
    'username' => "%YOUR_ADMIN_BACKEND_USER%",
    'password' => "%YOUR_ADMIN_BACKEND_PASSWORD%",
);

$testSKU = "%YOUR_TEST_SKU%";


// Request Admin Token 
$url = $config['shop_url']."/rest/all/V1/integration/admin/token";

$data = "{ \"username\": \"".$config['username']."\", \"password\": \"".$config['password']."\"}";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,  "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: application/json','accept: application/json')); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $data );

$response = curl_exec($ch);

if (!$response) 
{
    echo 'ERROR';
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($response);
echo '</pre>';

// Strip Response from unwanted Characters to save it as token
$token = str_ireplace('"', '', $response);


// Update qty for sku
$url = $config['shop_url']."/rest/V1/products/".$testSKU."/stockItems/1";

$data = '{"stockItem":{"qty":123}}';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,  "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: application/json','accept: application/json', 'Authorization: Bearer '.$token));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $data );

$response = curl_exec($ch);

if (!$response) 
{
    echo 'ERROR';
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($response);
echo '</pre>';
```

Tested on Magento 2.3.2

Comment: I recommend watching https://youtu.be/9OpjTwifhaE

Answer (score 0):

The APi user `'username' => 'username'` does not have proper access at sales section.

Please go to `admin>System>Extension>Intregation` and  open check your user is active or not .

**Second , this user is active then please check  open that use and  check it resource area setting**

Comment: what if the API user = admin user of Magento panel?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the PHP handler used by Apache on the Magento server. I also thought it was the PHP version, but then I realised the working version was using a different handler. I changed from cgi to suphp for the PHP version that was not working and the requests started to work. Interestingly, as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57028498/problem-with-magento-2-rest-authentication/59530132, POST requests would always work, but GET requests would fail. I have no idea why changing the handler solves the problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have been chasing my tail for hours on this ... :/

lm713: "Try changing the PHP handler used by Apache on the Magento server"

this did the trick, i am running magento 2 in cpanel environment and the php version was configured to use CGI as the PHP Handler. I changed it to suphp and all my api queries are now working!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on PHP 7.1.33
After I switched to 7.2.31 the issue was fixed. Not sure why it was.
Magento ver. 2.3.2

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was being caused by Apache. The "Consumer is not authorized"-error is a broad error, also being shown when the the Authorization-header is not being received by Magento.

Apparently Apache does not pass the Authorization-header to the website on default. It's Apache's default security behaviour.

Issue fixed by adding these lines to .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be a redirects issue. During redirect (response with Location 301 header) the Authorization header might be lost. So you can try to avoid redirects.
You can check redirects by getting cUrl code from Postman and add -v -L flags.